# sequelize multiple raw query cannot resolve previous promise

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I was learning node and try to build a node app using express and sequelize to manage DB data.

I have already build a module for node to connect to DB. Below is the code for the module:

sql.js:

```
var seq = require('./DBconfig.js');

module.exports = {
getTable1: function(o){
    return seq.query('SELECT * FROM Table1).then(function(results){
        o.table1 = results;
        return o;
    },
getTable2: function(o){
    return seq.query('SELECT * FROM Table2).then(function(results){
        o.table2 = results;
        return o;
    },
getTable3: function(o){
    return seq.query('SELECT * FROM Table3).then(function(results){
        o.table3 = results;
        return o;
    }
};
```

In my app I am able to use this module one by one perfectly.
However when I try to join them together:

route.js:

```
var sql = require('./sql.js');

app.get('/test', function(req,res){
    var a = {data:[{x: 1, y:1}]};
    sql.getTable1(a).then(sql.getTable2(result1)).then(
        sql.getTable3(result2)).then(function(result3){
             console.log(result3);
             res.send(result3);
    })
}
```

It always return: ReferenceError: result1 is not defined.
How can I get the promise work to get the resolve passed correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sql.getTable1(a).then(sql.getTable2(result1)).then(
    sql.getTable3(result2)).then(function(result3){
         console.log(result3);
         res.send(result3);
})
```

if you coded a function with (),
it will be called directly and replacing the fn(something) with the result
that's mean sql.getTable2(result1) is actually a result

```
sql.getTable1(a).then(sql.getTable2).then(
    sql.getTable3).then(function(result3){
         console.log(result3);
         res.send(result3);
})
```

try this,
the result will be automatically passed to next function as parameter